# Ways to find non trivial combination of zero from linearly dependent vectors

Tags: vectors, linear-programming, convex-hulls

For a set of m vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m>n$ is there an algorithm that finds the coefficients $\{\lambda_i\}$ not all zero such that $\lambda_1v_1+...+ \lambda_mv_m=0$?

If there is a constraint that $\lambda_i>0$ for the $i$’s used in order to get elements from the conic hull then such a combination doesn’t necessarily exist (for example if all scalar products are of the same sign) right?

Comment: Your linear combination can be written as $Ax = 0$ where the columns of A are your $v_m$ vectors and the components of $x$ are your $\lambda_m$. Then row reduction, reduce A to echelon form, that sort of thing should do it?

Comment: But it doesn’t explicitly give the coefficients corresponding to the $v_m$’s

Comment: $\lambda=x$ is quite explicit I would say. A solution $\lambda\geq 0$ can be found with the simplex method.

Comment: But that lambda is the set of coefficient for the row reduced matrix, not the original one

Comment: It solves $Ax=0$, i.e., $\sum_i a_i x_i = 0$.